# Clear SQL table before importing data (php)

Tags: php

Hi guys as the title says i'm trying to clear My SQL table before importing new data , but the problem only the last two rows appears not all of them .

I tried this using "TRUNCATE"

```
// clear table
$sqli = "TRUNCATE TABLE MyTable";
mysql_query($sqli);


$sql = 'INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES("'.$Data1.'","'.$Data2.'") ';
mysql_query($sql);
mysql_close();


$sql = 'SELECT * FROM MyTable';
    $req = mysql_query($sql);
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($req)){
        $D1 = $data['data1'];
        $D2 = $data['data2'];
        echo "$D1<br />
        $D2<br />";
    }
```

i can see only the last two rows.

Comment: But you inserted how many rows?

Comment: Could you explain more please - code above would appear to empty table, then import one row, then display that one row.

Comment: seems clear to me, you've truncated your table then inserted 2 values. is there something I'm not grasping?

Comment: if you have more rows, then use `mysql_fetch_assoc` rather than `mysql_fetch_array`, *n'est-ce pas?*

Comment: *before importing data* - How? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's not as hard as you think](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: This one seems to have caught a log in the river *Sam* - @JayBlanchard - It's lunchtime too. Time to clock out for a while ;-)

Comment: *10-4 Ralph* enjoy @Fred-ii-

Comment: *buon appetito Sam* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: Guys i think no one undrestand what i need exactly ,

Comment: Others asked you to clarify what you need, you THINK you have expressed that by "All what i need is i want to clear the table before adding new rows." but you haven't really.

Answer (score 0):

this is full code

part 1 : adding data into MySQL table

```
<?php
include( "............" );

$table = mta::getInput();
$Kills = $table[0];
$Deaths = $table[1];

// Send infos in MySQL
$base = mysql_connect ('........', '.........', '........');
mysql_select_db ('.........', $base);

$sql = 'INSERT INTO AccountsData VALUES("'.$Kills.'","'.$Deaths.'") ';
mysql_query($sql);
mysql_close();

// Return true if is added
// an other code here
?>
```

part 2 : get data from Mysql Table

```
<?php
    $base = mysql_connect ('.........', '.........', '.........');
    mysql_select_db ('..........', $base);

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM AccountsData';
    $req = mysql_query($sql);
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($req)){
        $Kills = $data['Kills'];
        $Deaths = $data['Deaths'];
        echo "$Kills<br />
        $Deaths<br />";
    }
    mysql_close();
?>
```

before using "TRUNCATE TABLE" it's working fine and i can see all rows

like this:

example

1. player 1
2. player 2
3. player 3
4. player 4

after using "TRUNCATE TABLE" i can see only the last row

4. player 4.

All what i need is i want to clear the table before adding new rows.

Sorry it's the first time that i use https://stackoverflow.com/